# in a df i want to check for equal values in other columns for each unique_id

Tags: python, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
result = []
       
     unique_id      length       frame
0           30          12       800
1           30          12       800 
2           30          12       700  
3           40         600      1200
4           40         800      1200
5           40         600       800
```

i need to check for each unique_id means for 30 index(0,1,2) length column should be consistent means all (0,1,2) is 12 and frame column all(0,1,2) should be 800. if not display index in to a list.

```
output: length =[4]
frame=[2,5]
```

can anyone show me way how i can achieve this.Thanks

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try `groupby().transform()`:

```
modes = df.groupby('unique_id').frame.transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])

out = (df['frame']==modes).sum()
# out: 4

frame = list(df[df['frame']!= modes].index)
# frame: [2,5]
```

Comment: Thankyou  verymuch appreciate your help. Got output for frame[2,5] but length=[3] not getting.really sorry in question above code it is length[3] but i wrote length[4].

Comment: Thanks buddy its all done i have achieved the required output,Thanks for your help.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve the same.